# Как вставить текст в форму на сайте

Tags: java, android

есть, скажем, сайт google.ru. Как туда вставить текст из getName() и нажать кнопку поиск..
вот код GeoPoint

```
package com.example.app;

import android.location.Location;

import java.util.Collection;

public class GeoPoint {

    public final double lat;
    public final double lon;
    public String name;

    public GeoPoint(double lat, double lon, String name) {
        this.lat = lat;
        this.lon = lon;
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    public GeoPoint(Location location) {
        this.lat = location.getLatitude();
        this.lon = location.getLongitude();
    }

    public static GeoPoint getNearestLocation(GeoPoint current, Collection<GeoPoint> locations) {
        GeoPoint res = null;
        float lastDisance = Float.MAX_VALUE;
        float locDistance[] = new float[1];
        for (GeoPoint loc: locations) {
            Location.distanceBetween(current.lat, current.lon,
                    loc.lat, loc.lon, locDistance);
            if (res == null || locDistance[0] < lastDisance) {
                res = loc;
                lastDisance = locDistance[0];
            }
        }
        return res;
    }




}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста поясните как связан name который нужно вставить и остальной код.

Comment: просто getName() в коде.. помогите, как вставить то

Comment: А вам, совершенно случайно, не [геокодирование](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/) нужно?

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой способ посмотреть какой запрос формирует сайт когда вы жмете на кнопку, после заполнения полей. Потом пробуете повторить похожий запрос но уже со своими данными из приложения, результаты парсите.
+ Не совсем ясно имеете ли вы доступ с сайту\есть ли у сайта api.
+ Под Js есть либа SlimerJS, вот [статья](http://habrahabr.ru/post/247847/). В ней примерно то что вам нужно, но увы под Android я аналогов не знаю.

Answer (score 0):

Открывать страницу по ссылке `https://www.google.ru/#newwindow=1&q=ВАШ ТЕКСТ ИЗ getName()` и дальше делать с ней что потребуется. Это можно сделать разными способами, к примеру библиотекой https://github.com/square/okhttp